# How can I change my data to make it work with loss: mean squared error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am using the mnist dataset(digits), and would like to implement mean squared error loss function, however I have the following error:

ValueError: A target array with shape (60000, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 10) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

this is my code:
Originally, I tried **sparse_categorical_crossentropy**
Code modified from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis = 1) 
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis = 1) 

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

How can I reshape my data so that it works with MSE?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you missing something very important here. You are trying to use a metric used in *regression* (Mean-Squared-Error) for a *classification* task (predicting classes). These two objectives are different tasks in the machine learning world.

If like to try it anyway, just reshape your  last layer to one output-neuron and ReLU-activation:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
```

One output neuron and ReLU-activation since your label is just the (integer) numbers from 0 to 9. Sigmoid gives you continuous values between 0 and 1, so this won't bring you any success in this case.

Keep in mind your model doesn't do classification anymore, it will give you a continuous number between 0 and inf. So don't be surprised if you get e.g.  3.1415 as output if you feed an image of a 3 into your model. The model tries now to produce outputs as close as possible to the number in the label.